# Delayed reading from generated texture in OpenGL

Tags: performance, opengl, render-to-texture

I use a shader program to generate some data in a texture in OpenGL, and I want to read the data back in from OpenGL to use it on the CPU. Normally, of course, reading texture data involves flushing the pipeline, so that the data is actually there and ready, with obvious consequences for performance.

However, I don't actually need the data immediately, and could precisely as well wait until it's ready and then read it. Is there any way to do this? I guess I could perhaps wait until I'm swapping buffers anyway and read the data then, but would this cause any performance issues anyway (due to having to flush twice or something)? Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asynchronous image data transfers can be done with [Pixel Buffer Objects](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/pixel_buffer_object.txt). The Idea is that you create a PBO and initiate the texutre readback into it, and the GL will do the transfer asynchronously. It will only have to force a sync if you try to access the PBO before the transfer is completed.

You could further combine this with a [fence sync object](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/sync.txt) via [`glFenceSync()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFenceSync.xml) and actually query if the transfer has been completed before trying to map/read back the PBO, and if not so, do something else on the CPU instead of wasting time waiting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This should do what I want, but I don't supposed there's any way to do it with OpenGL 2.0?

Comment: @Dolda2000: PBOs were promoted core in GL2.1. If you really have a need to target 2.0 as opposed to 2.1, you might still be lucky as this extension might be widely available on 2.0 implementations. But I'm not aware of any asynchronous readback features in core 2.0.

Comment: Oh really? I didn't think it was that early. In that case, I guess there's problem at all. Thanks!